# Async function that calls jqXHR.done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async.js

I have asynchronous function that calls a function that returns a jQuery XMLHTTPRequest (jqXHR) object, that, when done, does some work and invokes callback. Unfortunately, when I use said function before and after other functions in `async.waterfall()`, the function's `.done()` seems to get invoked **after** everything else was already done (including the functions after this, and the success/fail callback at the end of `async.waterfall()`).

The function definition looks like this:

```
function snapPotholeCoordsToRoad(potholeCollection, callback)
{
    var DEBUG = true;
    // guarantee that callback is function
    if ((callback) && (typeof(callback) !== 'function')) throw new TypeError('callback is something, but not a function. Thrown from snapPotholeCoordsToRoad().');
    // for each element of potholeCoordinates
    for (var key in potholeCoordinates)
    {
        (function itr(k, m) { 
            if (m === potholeCoordinates[key].length) return;
            if (DEBUG) console.log('called before the jqXHR.done()');
            // if element (PotholeData) not snapped to road
            if (!potholeCoordinates[k][m].isSnappedToRoad())
            {
                // get road coordinates for element
                getRoadCoordinates(potholeCoordinates[k][m])
                // replace element's coordinates with those road coordinates
                .done(function(newCoords) { 
                    potholeCoordinates[k][m].setCoordinates(newCoords.snappedPoints[0].location);
                    potholeCoordinates[k][m].isSnappedToRoad(true);
                    if (DEBUG) console.log('called after jqXHR.done()');
                    itr(k, m+1);
                })
            }
            else itr(k, m+1);
        })(key, 0);
    }
    if (callback)
    {
        callback(null);
    }
}
```

where `potholeCoordinates` is an `Object` of `Array`s of `PotholeData`

`getRoadCoordinates()` simply looks like this:

```
/* snaps the coordinates to the nearest road
 * Parameters:
 *  • coords : coordinates object`
 * Returns: 
 *  • coordinates, snapped to road 
 * NOTE: the points you're looking for are accessible via the snappedPoints member of the returned object (in done() or success()) 
 */
function getRoadCoordinates(coords)
{
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url : 'https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads',
        data: { 
            key : API_KEY,
            interpolate : true,
            path : coords.lat + ', ' + coords.lng
        }
     });
}
```

...and the `async.waterfall()` is like this:

```
async.waterfall([//fetchServerPotholeData,  // for some reason, this function is not receiving data
            function(callback) { 
                fetchServerPotholeData(data, callback);
            },
            fetchRoadCoords,
            snapPotholeCoordsToRoad,
            addPotholeMarkers
            ], function(err, result) { 
                if (!err) { 
                    console.log('result == ' + result);
                    console.log('Everything successfully done. Enjoy your map!'); 

                }
                else 
                {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            }
        )
```

/* it sits inside a function that passes it `data`. */

At runtime, I get console output similar to :

```
called before the jqXHR.done()
result == undefined
Everything successfully done. Enjoy your map!
called after jqXHR.done()
```

What must I change to make the `.done()` execute during its ticks inside those loops, followed by the rest of the code?

Comment: Your `snapPotholeCoordsToRoad` calls its `callback` function immediately towards the end of the function. That's why `async.waterfall` thinks it's done and moves onto the next task.

Comment: The solution, then, is to refactor this nested for-loop using `async`'s loop functions, with preferrably the first for-loop having a done callback, where I invoke `callback()` itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the error, after worrying about this all day, within minutes of posting this here!

**what I did**

Before the first `for` loop, I save a copy of the keys of potholeCoordinates

```
var keys = Object.keys(potholeCoordinates);
```

and inside that `.done()` callback, at the very end, right before

```
itr(k, m+1);
```

I check for if I'm on the last object in the last array, with:

```
if ((k === keys[keys.length - 1]) && (callback)) return callback(null);
```

**EDIT**: I forgot to include that I did away with the

```
if (callback) 
{
    callback(null);
}
```

outside that for loop

/* I should probably now work on refactoring this code so as to actually use its parameters like they should be.... */

Comment: Promises would probably make this code quite a bit cleaner. I suggest checking them out if you haven't already.